# Applying functions to DataFrame columns in plots

Tags: pandas

I'd like to apply functions to columns of a DataFrame when plotting them.

I understand that the standard way to plot when using Pandas is the .plot method.

How can I do math operations within this method, say for example multiply two columns in the plot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Series actually have a plot method as well, so it should work to apply

```
(df['col1'] * df['col2']).plot()
```

Otherwise, if you need to do this more than once it would be the usual thing to make a new column in your dataframe:

```
df['newcol'] = df['col1'] * df['col2']
```